# How to change the subreport source in a run time?

Tags: c#, reporting, reportviewer

I'm creating some report in C# and I have 2 types of them. The header and footer are the same but the middle part is different. I have a type parameter to determine which type report is it. But I don't know how to change the source subreport. The field "Use this report as subreport" unfortunately doesn't allow to enter the expression so I cannot define the necessary report by condition. And I don't know how to do that from the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Just put 2 different subreports on the main report and use expression to determine which one should be shown, which - to be hidden. Stupid but works.